# The accuracy of oracle when compare two date in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

It is in two procedures which are running in order. In procedure one, the running timestamp of system time is `2019/5/30 12:02:58.100`. The sql is as below

```
insert into A(xxx,xxx,cdate) values(xxx,xxx,sysdate)
```

And I find the cdate field of this inserted row is `2019/5/30 12:02:58`, without the millisecond.

And then procedure two runs, the running timestamp of system time is `2019/5/30 12:02:58.200`. The SQL is as below

```
select xxx from A where cdate<sysdate
```

This returns none result. It is weird because I just inserted a row with cdate `2019/5/30 12:02:58`. This should be less than `sysdate`.

1. When Oracle stores date value like `2019/5/30 12:02:58`, does it throw millsecond away or does it just store it in background and not show it?
2. While comparing `cdate<sysdate`, which two values does it use? I guess it is using `2019/5/30 12:02:58 < 2019/5/30 12:02:58`, so this returns false.

Comment: table definition please?

Comment: A common table like User(id,name,age,cdate), while cdate is when the row is created.

Comment: When you're asked for a table definition you're expected to provide the  **data type** for the columns, as that is usually pertinent to the problem, as it is here. A column defined as a DATE will store only whole seconds (rounded down). To keep milliseconds we must define a column as TIMESTAMP. Also note that `sysdate` is a DATE whereas `systimestamp` is a TIMESTAMP.

Answer (score 1):

> When Oracle stores date value like `2019/5/30 12:02:58`, does it throw millsecond away or does it just store it in background and not show it?

A date value does not have any millisecond component to throw away. [`sysdate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/SYSDATE.html#GUID-807F8FC5-D72D-4F4D-B66D-B0FE1A8FA7D2) returns a DATE [data type](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-7B72E154-677A-4342-A1EA-C74C1EA928E6):

> This data type contains the datetime fields YEAR, MONTH, DAY, HOUR, MINUTE, and SECOND. It does not have fractional seconds or a time zone.

In your procedures you are looking at a TIMESTAMP value:

> This data type contains the datetime fields YEAR, MONTH, DAY, HOUR, MINUTE, and SECOND. It contains fractional seconds but does not have a time zone.

... or a variant that does have a time zone, like TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE, as returned by [`systimestamp`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/SYSTIMESTAMP.html#GUID-FCED18CE-A875-4D5D-9178-3DE4FA956516):

> This data type contains the datetime fields YEAR, MONTH, DAY, HOUR, MINUTE, SECOND, TIMEZONE_HOUR, and TIMEZONE_MINUTE. It has fractional seconds and an explicit time zone.

---

> While comparing `cdate<sysdate`, which two values does it use? I guess it is using `2019/5/30 12:02:58 < 2019/5/30 12:02:58`, so this returns false.

As your insert statement is using `sysdate`, it doesn't really matter at this point whether `cdate` is defined as DATE or TIMESTAMP, if the latter then the fraction seconds part is just truncated to zero. And `sysdate` also returns a DATE, so yes, it is either doing:

```
2019-05-30 12:02:58 < 2019-05-30 12:02:58
```

or

```
2019-05-30 12:02:58.000 < 2019-05-30 12:02:58
```

which may involve an implicit cast. Either way the result is indeed false.

---

If you want to compare values that might be within the same second then you have to use a TIMESTAMP. Define your column as one of the TIMESTAMP variants as appropriate, and then use `systimestamp` instead of `sysdate` both for your insert and for the comparison. It all has to be timestamps - if any part of what you do stays as a date then at some point the fractional seconds will be lost and you'll be in the same position you are now.

Answer (score 0):

If your column is a DATE type then it doesn't store milliseconds. SYSDATE doesn't return them either. Ensure your column is a TIMESTAMP with a suitable number for fractional precision to store the milliseconds you want, and ensure you're comparing it with SYSTIMESTAMP